# How to define lazy Module paths in angular2 and load specific module for that path

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, lazy-loading

I have different components and routes based on roles. Now i have defined routes as for certain components as below

```
Login Module 
path: '', loadChildren:'app/login/login.module#LoginModule';

Register Module 
path:'', loadChildren: 'app/register/register.module#LoginModule'

Dashboard Module
path:'' loadChildren:'app/dashboard/dashboard.module#dashboardModule'

User Profile Module
path:'' loadChildren:'app/user-profile/user-profile.module#UserProfileModule'
```

Now whenever I navigate to login or register page all the listed module chunks  are getting loaded all together and page is slightly delayed and stucks until module chunks are not loading. Does anyone has idea how to define path and stop the unwanted module load on specific path. Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: why is the path same for all the routes ?

Comment: What path should i give ?? as i am accessing the module as below    http://mydomain/login,  http://mydomain/register, http://mydomain/dashboard, http://mydomain/user-profile

Comment: can you post your whole routing file ?

Comment: Yup wait a minute

Comment: const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: LoginComponent },                                                                                                                                       
    { path: '', component: RegisterComponent },
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forChild(routes);

Comment: { path: 'login', loadChildren: 'app/login/login.module#LoginModule' , data: { preload: true }},

    { path: 'register', loadChildren: 'app/register/register.module#RegisterModule', data: { preload: true } }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to specify a route under your module will be executed.

Note that all lazy-loaded module must follow these three rules.

1. The module which you want to lazy load they should have one parent route.
2. Dont import module in your `app.module.ts`. Because if you do then no point of lazy loading
3. Your will need to configure under one route in your `app.routes`.

So to answer your question you will need config like this..

```
{
// Login Module 
path: 'login', loadChildren:'app/login/login.module#LoginModule';

// Register Module ,
path:'register', loadChildren: 'app/register/register.module#LoginModule'

// Dashboard Module
path:'dashboard', loadChildren:'app/dashboard/dashboard.module#dashboardModule'

// User Profile Module
path:'profile', loadChildren:'app/user-profile/user-profile.module#UserProfileModule'

}
```

So whenever you will hit `login` route it will load the `#LoginModule`. In your login module should export routes like this

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { 
        path: '', 
        children: [
           {
           path: '',
           component: YourComponentToLoad 
           }
        ]
    }
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class LoginRoutingModule {

}
```

Also, in your `app-routing.module.ts` you can define preloading strategy as following so that after the app is initialized, lazy modules will start loading immediately. So, when user clicks on a link and wants to see a lazy loaded module, it'll be ready.

`app-routing.module.ts`

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules})],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
```

Comment: Also, you should use `preloadingStrategy` in your root Routing module in which you call `RouterModule.forRoot` so that lazy loaded modules will start loading immediately after the app is initialized.

Comment: Ya I am using preloadingStartegy but what if the routes are protected by guards. I have certain components that are protected by routed and defined in one single module that how to define path for those components

Comment: @user5309516 are you using  `canActivate ` guard?

Comment: Yes I am using canActivate

Comment: Yes, then it would work fine. I use the same approach.

Comment: can you show me code for defining route with lazy module path

Comment: From the code above what should i write in LoginModule routes ?? that is const routes: Routes = [
     // your routes for login module ???
]

Comment: @user5309516 Updated the answer.

Comment: Ok great!! Thanks I will try the same that was what i was mistaking it. children. Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: What if my LoginRoutingModule has 3 different routes than how to define those paths in app.routing .ts

Comment: @user5309516 You don't need to define that in your `app.routing.ts` it will be configured in `LoginRoutingModule` by adding more objects pairs under its `children` property.

Comment: Okay but then what will be the path in my app.routing.ts because sometimes login.module.chunk.js loads on certain routes even though it is not defined any where only path in app.routing.ts is {path:'' ,loadChildren:app/login/login.module#LoginModule} So is the path:'' is making is load ?? also when i navigate to certain route module takes slight delay to load do you know how to smooth that transition

Comment: @user5309516 you don't need to import `LoginModule` anywhere in your routes or module. If you do it then no point of lazy load.

Comment: @Abhilash can you create a demo in https://stackblitz.com/ and add some static routes and dynamic routes implementing lazy module concept. It would be great help.

Comment: I have four pages that has multiple dynamic routes. Now i have defined routes of these pages in their respective routing module and in app.routing.ts i have just defined like this {path:'', loadChildren:app/comp-a/comp-a.module#CompAModule} , {path:'', loadChildren:app/comp-b/comp-b.module#CompBModule} , {path:'', loadChildren:app/comp-c/comp-c.module#CompCModule} , {path:'', loadChildren:app/comp-d/comp-d.module#CompDModule} So i have problem with these 4 pages only

Comment: @user5309516 Okay. Will put up a demo and let you know here.

Comment: Thanks! that will a Great help

Comment: @user5309516 I will try to put it up as soon as I can, as I am a bit stuck in work.

Comment: hello @user5309516 I have been busy lately but here's your demo. Follow this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-45brfy

Comment: Thanks @Abhilash. Nice one