# Lazy Module paths in angular2 still loads all the chunk.js together on homepage

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, lazy-loading

As per the comments [How to define lazy Module paths in angular2 and load specific module for that path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48760758/how-to-define-lazy-module-paths-in-angular2-and-load-specific-module-for-that-pa/48760968#48760968) i have implemented the routes for my modules but still when i first hit the url all the module chunks are getting loaded together I don't understand why this is occurring again. Below is my code

```
mailbox.routing.ts

 const routes: Routes = [
       {
        path: '',
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                component: MailboxComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]
            }
        ]
    }
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(routes);

mailbox.module.ts
    @NgModule({
        imports: [
            routing,
            SharedModule,
        ],
        declarations: [
            MailboxComponent
        ],    
      });

app.routing.ts

 { path: 'mailbox', loadChildren: 'app/mailbox/mailbox.module#MailboxModule', data: { preload: true } },
        { path: 'mailbox/:threadId', loadChildren: 'app/mailbox/mailbox.module#MailboxModule', data: { preload: true } },
    }
```

Same way different routes are defined yet all the chunks are getting loaded on the first page. Does anyone has idea to resolve this.

Comment: I guess your MailBoxModule ist still declared in your imports array in your AppModule. Please show us your AppModule file.

Comment: No its not present

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when you have imported the module in your main module i.e. app.module.ts in your case. So if you have imported mailbox.module.ts in your app.module.ts then remove it. If you are using lazy routing you should not import that module in your main module, of which you have given path in your loadChildren.